# Cannot take inverse fourier transform of a function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, matlab

I am trying to get the inverse fourier transform of the following function:

$$\frac{ (i*k)}{( 1 - e^{(i*k*T)} ); }$$

Where t is constant. Is there a way to approach this?

I have tried the following in MATLAB:

```
syms k t T
F = (i*k)/( 1 - exp(i*k*T) );
ifourier(F, k, t);
```

and had

```
ans = -(fourier(k/(exp(T*k*1i) - 1), k, -t)*1i)/(2*pi)
```

for some reason.

Then I tried to evaluate merely the given function

```
 FourierResult = fourier(k/(exp(k*1i) - 1), k, -t);
```

and had the same answer (matlab did not evaluate both fouriers)

is this a kind of unsolved fourier transform that no one had a solution yet? Or is there a good way to approach this?

Comment: This FT is singular at $k=2 \pi m/T$ for any nonzero integer $m$.

Comment: Oh right! That makes sense. I needed to filter out $$\frac{( 1 - e^{(i*k*T)} ) }{ (i*k)}$$ so I just took its inverse and was going to multiply it with the original Fourier of my input (Im using this on signal processing). So does this mean its impossible to filter this out? If not, what can I do to avoid this singularity but still cancel out this Fourier?